# GSL multiroot finding mode Hybrid function load with Mathematica : Crash

Tags: compile, mac-os-x, librarylink, c++, ccompilerdriver

Hi everyone

I work on a Mac M1 Sonoma 14.3 with Mathematica 12.3.1 and 14.0

I have an issue when using a C++ multiroot finding from GSL library.
I used this example : https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/multiroots.html
that i simplifed and added to it the wrapper to do the link with mathematica (I added a log also which is write in a file) :

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include "WolframCompileLibrary.h"
#include "WolframNumericArrayLibrary.h"
#include "WolframSparseLibrary.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multiroots.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void writeLog(const std::string& message) {
  std::ofstream logFile;

  // Open the file in append mode. If the file does not exist, it will be created.
  // but be carefull to give a correct folder name
  logFile.open("logWithMathematica.txt", std::ios_base::app);

  if (logFile.is_open()) {
      logFile << message << std::endl;
      logFile.close();
  } else {

  }
}

int print_state (size_t iter, gsl_multiroot_fsolver * s)
{
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "iter = " << iter
    << " x = " << gsl_vector_get (s->x, 0) << " " << gsl_vector_get (s->x, 1)
    << " f(x) = " << gsl_vector_get (s->f, 0) << " " << gsl_vector_get (s->f, 1) << "\n";

std::string str = oss.str();
writeLog(str);
    return 0;
}

int function (const gsl_vector * x, void *params,
              gsl_vector * f)
{
  writeLog("start function");
  const double x0 = gsl_vector_get (x, 0);
  const double x1 = gsl_vector_get (x, 1);
  writeLog("enter in Function : after x0 and x1 " + std::to_string(x0) + " " + std::to_string(x1));
  gsl_vector_set (f, 0, 1 - x0);
  gsl_vector_set (f, 1, x1 - x0 * x0);
  writeLog("enter in Function : after y0 and y1 " + std::to_string(1 - x0) + " " + std::to_string(x1 - x0 * x0));
  writeLog("end function");
  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


void functionSolve()
{
  writeLog("inside functionSolve");
  const gsl_multiroot_fsolver_type *T;
  gsl_multiroot_fsolver *s;

  int status;
  size_t i, iter = 0;

  gsl_multiroot_function f = {&function, 2, {}};

  gsl_vector *x = gsl_vector_alloc (2); // dim=2

  gsl_vector_set (x, 0, -10.0);
  gsl_vector_set (x, 1, -5.0);
  writeLog("just before solver allocation" + std::to_string(-10.0) + " " + std::to_string(-5.0));
  T = gsl_multiroot_fsolver_hybrids;
  s = gsl_multiroot_fsolver_alloc (T, 2);
  writeLog("just before set solver");
  gsl_multiroot_fsolver_set (s, &f, x); // it seems something is wrong here, it crashes.
  writeLog("just before do while loop"); // it never arrives here.

  do
    {
      iter++;
      status = gsl_multiroot_fsolver_iterate (s);
      writeLog("during iteration");
      print_state (iter, s);
      if (status)   /* check if solver is stuck */
        break;

      status =
        gsl_multiroot_test_residual (s->f, 1e-7);
    }
  while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < 10);
  writeLog("out of do while");
  gsl_multiroot_fsolver_free (s);
  gsl_vector_free (x);
  writeLog("memory free");

}



// the link with mathematica 
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int functionSolve_dll(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument res)
{
  if (Argc != 0) return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR;
    
  writeLog("Start");
  functionSolve();
  writeLog("after functionSolve");
  MArgument_setUTF8String(res,"done!");
  
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Then i compile it from Mathematica :

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
(* path to the GSL library *)

gslLibPath = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/lib/";
gslIncludePath = "/opt/homebrew/opt/gsl/include";
depGSL = FileNames["*.dylib", gslLibPath]
(* we put the lib in the same directory *)
targetPath = NotebookDirectory[];
libName = "Lib_gen_by_mathematica";
(* the code for the newton search *)
sourceFile = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "n_dim_newton.cpp"}];
(* we create the dylib file *)
libFile = 
  CreateLibrary[Flatten@{sourceFile}, libName, 
   "LibraryDirectories" -> {gslLibPath},
   "IncludeDirectories" -> {gslIncludePath, NotebookDirectory[]}, 
   "TargetDirectory" -> targetPath, Language -> "C++", 
   "CompileOptions" -> {"-std=c++17", "-lgsl", "-lgslcblas"}];
```

then Load it :

```
(* we load the lib in the kernel *)

TestNdimNewton = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[
   NotebookDirectory[] <> "Lib_gen_by_mathematica.dylib", 
   "functionSolve_dll", {}, "UTF8String"];
```

-> For the moment every thing is executed well

**The problem** is when i execute the function load from mathematica
I have a kernel crash in Mathematica (I don't know if it's the good term but it's equivalent of a Quit in Mathematica)

```
(* we lauch the lib: it crashes the kernel ! *)
TestNdimNewton[]
```

The log indicated me that the crash is during the line 75 of my C++ code with :   gsl_multiroot_fsolver_set (s, &f, x);
during this commande it goes 3 times throw my function to solve
and it crash just after :

```
Start
inside functionSolve
just before solver allocation-10.000000 -5.000000
just before set solver
start function
enter in Function : after x0 and x1 -10.000000 -5.000000
enter in Function : after y0 and y1 11.000000 -105.000000
end function
start function
enter in Function : after x0 and x1 -10.000000 -5.000000
enter in Function : after y0 and y1 11.000000 -104.999997
end function
start function
enter in Function : after x0 and x1 -10.000000 -5.000000
enter in Function : after y0 and y1 11.000000 -105.000000
end function
```

Something to note is when i use this code (without the Mathematica library and the wrapper) compile in the terminal it works fine and also when i do a library .dylib (without again the Mathematica library and the wrapper) and use it in python it works also fine

I don't know if it's because the GSL fonction that i use is incompatible with Mathematica or something else

If you have any idea or sugestion to make it work or why it will never work :)

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hm. You documented this pretty well. Unfortunately, I cannot find the reason for this. On my system (Mac M1 Sonoma 14.3.1 with _Mathematica_ 13.3.1 precisely the same happens. You say that everythings works fine if you compile this as stand-alone. My guess is that there is some clash between some library that both gsl and _Mathematica_ try to link. I had the strong hunch that this was related to BLAS. Mathematica links per default to OpenBLAS, I guess. So I tried to remove `"-lgslcblas"`. It compiled and the program ran, but it crashed at the very same point.

Comment: I don't know if it's can help to find the issue but : 
i have already succeed to use another function from GSL in mathematica 
It was a one dimensional root-finding : gsl_root_fsolver_brent
Which is describe here : https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/roots.html
And I had also compiled it with ```"-lgslcblas"```
And it worked perfectly on Mathematica

Comment: Hi Alex, it is indeed good to know that gsl _can_ work with _Mathematica_. However, I don't think that any BLAS routine will ever avtually be called in `gsl_root_fsolver_brent` because there is just no multidimensional linear algebra involved there. I've got the hunch that the first two steps of the hybrid method also does not do that...

Comment: I will just mention that GSL is far from a great library even for power of 2. https://cnrs.hal.science/hal-04116310/document